# JQuery AutoComplete textbox Returning Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, jquery

I have trried to do autocomplete text box using jquery with the below mentioned code, but I can't achieve it,I am getting error in jquery. Thanks in Advance.

AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ajax_Using_Jquery.AutoCompleteTextBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ajax Auto Complete Using Jquery</title>

      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var UserNameInput;

     $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#<%=txtName.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx/getUserNames",
                        data: "{'TextBoxVal':'" + document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID%>').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("error ");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div>
    User Name : &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx.cs :

```
public List<string> getUserNames(string TextBoxVal)
    {
        string strCon;
        List<string> objList = new List<string>();
        strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpNameFetch"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select EmpName from newTb2 where EmpName like '%"+TextBoxVal+"%'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (objReader.Read())
        {
            objList.Add(objReader["EmpName"].ToString());
        }
        Response.Write(objList.ToString());
        con.Close();
        return objList;

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 500 internal server error Server Error in '/' Application. Unknown web method getUserNames. Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method getUserNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this instead of calling AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx page I added a new service and  called asmx page with  adding this piece of code in the asmx.cs page

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Ajax_Using_Jquery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AutoCompleteFetchService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AutoCompleteFetchService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        [WebMethod]
        public List<string> getUserNames(string TextBoxVal)
        {
            string strCon;
            List<string> objList = new List<string>();
            strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpNameFetch"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select EmpName from newTb2 where EmpName like '%" + TextBoxVal + "%'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (objReader.Read())
            {
                objList.Add(objReader["EmpName"].ToString());
            }

            con.Close();
            return objList;

        }

    }
}
```

In aspx page I coded like,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ajax_Using_Jquery.AutoCompleteTextBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ajax Auto Complete Using Jquery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-1.9.0.mini.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
     <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
             source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     url: "AutoCompleteFetchService.asmx/getUserNames",
                     data: "{'TextBoxVal':'" + document.getElementById('txtName1').value + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (data1) {
                         response(data1.d);
                         if (data1.d == "" || data1.d == null || typeof (data1.d) == 'undefined') {

                             response(["no search found"]);
                         }
                     },
                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert("error " + XMLHttpRequest);
                         alert("error " + textStatus);
                         alert("error " + errorThrown);
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     });
    </script>
  <%--  <link href="StyleSheet/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />--%>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div>
    User Name : &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="txtName1" class="autosuggest"  />
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont't use inline SQL parameters, you will be prone to SQL injection. Use SqlParameter to avoid sql injection. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of error you're getting, but  have you tried comment the line below?
You're already sending a response, there is no need to write a response explicit.
You might want to convert your method in a web method also.

```
 Response.Write(objList.ToString());
```

Comment: 500 internal server error                                                                   Server Error in '/' Application. Unknown web method getUserNames. Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method getUserNames

Answer (score 0):

you should make this method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> getUserNames(string TextBoxVal)
{
    string strCon;
    List<string> objList = new List<string>();
    strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpNameFetch"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select EmpName from newTb2 where EmpName like '%"+TextBoxVal+"%'", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (objReader.Read())
    {
        objList.Add(objReader["EmpName"].ToString());
    }
    //Response.Write(objList.ToString());
    //remove the above because you can not use Resonse.Write here
    con.Close();
    return objList;

}
```

Try use firebug plugin this will give you lots of information about the  error you get

Comment: I removed that response.write but the error persists, In firefox the xhr shows 200 ok but in jquery error alert is displayed,

Comment: I am not using web service i am using the same page (AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx & AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx.cs)

Comment: you can have [WebMethod] inside any code begind in your asp.net application

Comment: Yeah I added that but I am getting 500 internal server error . I found this error using fire bug. The error is looking like    Server Error in '/' Application.
Unknown web method getUserNames.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method getUserNames.